# How to stop MetaPost drawings from overlapping on different lines in ConText?

Tags: vertical-alignment, context, metapost

I have an itemized list. On several lines there are some boxes, drawn in MetaPost. I used `\inframed[location=line]` to make them vertically centered on the line. The problem is, they are overlapping each other:

```
\define[1]\drawbox{%
    \scale[width=.1\textwidth]{%
        \startMPcode        
            draw (0,0)--(100,0)--(100,100)--(0,100)--(0,0);
        \stopMPcode%
    }%
}

\define[3]\showfacts{%
    \inframed[frame=off, location=line]{%
        \drawbox{#1}%
    }%
    {\it #2}\ #3%
}%

\starttext
    This is some text.
    \startitemize[n]
        \item \showfacts{a}{x}{3}
        \item \showfacts{b}{y}{4}
    \stopitemize
\stoptext
```

Is there a way to make it so the next item (item #2) appears lower, so that the MetaPost art don't overlap? Additionally, so it isn't so close to "This is some text".? The appearance should be more like this:

```
This is some text.
    _____
   |     |
1. |     | x 3
   |_____|
    _____
   |     |
2. |     | y 4
   |_____|
```

How can I give a greater space automatically when the line has a MetaPost object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`location=middle`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/0189223a1a40debb4cb3b146ce182eb806cd28f2/tex/context/base/mkiv/pack-rul.mkiv#L1855-L1861).  The option [`location=line`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/0189223a1a40debb4cb3b146ce182eb806cd28f2/tex/context/base/mkiv/pack-rul.mkiv#L1832-L1837) just sets both height and depth of the enclosed object to `.5\lineheight`.

*N.B.:* `\inframed` is just a shortcut for `\framed[location=low]`, so by overriding the location you defeat this shortcut.  Might as well use plain `\framed` then.

```
\define[1]\drawbox{%
    \scale[width=.1\textwidth]{%
        \startMPcode        
            draw (0,0)--(100,0)--(100,100)--(0,100)--(0,0);
        \stopMPcode%
    }%
}

\define[3]\showfacts{%
    \framed[frame=off,location=middle]{%
        \drawbox{#1}%
    }%
    {\it #2}\ #3%
}%

\starttext
    This is some text.
    \startitemize[n]
        \item \showfacts{a}{x}{3}
        \item \showfacts{b}{y}{4}
    \stopitemize
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I must say that this is the first time I have encountered normalMPboxdepth. Would you mind adding an explanation for that as well?

Comment: @Aditya Oops, that was a leftover of an earlier experiment.  It is not needed here.  To see what it does, check [`meta-ini.mkiv`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/0189223a1a40debb4cb3b146ce182eb806cd28f2/tex/context/base/mkiv/meta-ini.mkiv#L678-L687).